# Linux Apache VM Port Issue

Tags: rhel, virtualbox, apache-httpd

I have a RHEL VirtualBox VM in bridged mode so it can be accessed from the LAN. RHEL hosts an HTTPD server configured to listen on ports 80, 8080 and 8181. `netstat -an | grep :8` confirms that port 80, 8080 and 8181 are `LISTEN`ing.

The VM's IP address is `192.168.204.239`. From the host machine, using a browser, I can hit the URL `http://192.168.204.239:80`. But I cannot hit URLs with ports `8080` and `8181`. I have turned off the firewall on the VM.

What gives? How can I solve this issue?

**EDIT #1**

I have turned the VM's firewall off via `/etc/init.d/iptables stop`. Still, port 8080 and 8181 are not accessible from a browser in the host machine. Only port 80 is.

Comment: Which operating system do your use? So where the virtual box is running.

Comment: Is there a firewall running on the underlying physical machine running the VM that could be blocking outbound connections to those ports?

Comment: "But I cannot hit URLs with ports 8080 and 8181." What happens when you try?